# Can I use paste to call an element in a data frame?

Tags: r

```
myfunc <- function(vname, X){
  X$R'vname' = 0
  X$R'vname' [X$Y'vname'>0.254] = 1
}
```

That is, if I call myfunc(12, X) the following happens

```
  X$R12 = 0
  X$R12 [X$Y12>0.254] = 1
```

I know that paste0("R",12) is going to return R12, but I don't know how can I use that to call X$R12 or X$Y12

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
myfunc <- function(vname, X){
  vname2 = paste('R', vname, sep="")
  vname3 =  paste('Y', vname, sep="")
  X[vname2] = 0
  X[vname2][X[[vname3]]>0.254] = 1
}
```

For the record, though, you could do

X$R12 <- X$Y12>0.254

This will give you a TRUE/FALSE which is the same as 1/0 in R stat models.

Comment: Thanks. One little thing, you have [[vname3 but it should be [vname3 I think.

Comment: Actually, in this case I used the double [[ on purpose. The doubles x[['val1']] will give you the column while x['val'] will give you an error with a data.frame. Try experimenting to see.